# Can two vector bundles with the same Chern classes be topologically different?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

so I know that two vector bundles with the same Chern classes can still be different. My question is however, if they can also be topologically different or if they are necessarily topologically equivalent.

The reason to ask this is basically that all other characteristic classes I can think of (like Pontragyn classes, etc.) seem to be determined by the Chern classes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't the tangent bundle of the 2-sphere one such? Its Chern classes are zero, but it is not trivial even topologically.

Comment: Are you asking whether two complex vector bundles $\xi, \xi' \to M$ of the same rank are equivalent iff $c(\xi) = c(\xi')$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can certainly be topologically different, for you can take the product of a any bundle with a trivial bundle without changing the chern classes, but you do change the dimension of the total space, and once you've done that, the two total-space manifolds are not going to be homeomorphic.

To be explicit: let $\epsilon$ be a trivial line bundle over $\Bbb CP^1$, and let $\tau$ be the tangent bundle to $\Bbb CP^1$. Then the Chern classes of $\epsilon \oplus \tau$ are the same as those of $\tau$. But the total space of $\tau$ is a 4-manifold, while the total space of $\epsilon \oplus \tau$ is a 6-manifold.

Comment: Okay, I didn't think of that. But is it also possible without change the rank of the vector bundle? Or put differently can I find a vector bundle that cannot be deformed continuously to the corresponding split bundle?

Comment: That's a different question (and frankly, I don't actually understand what you're asking). If your question is "are there two bundles whose total spaces have the same dimension but whose Chern classes are the same?", then you need to have the Chern classes be in the same group (else they cannot be compared). So the question becomes "Are there bundles $\sigma$ and $\tau$ over the same base-space $M$ whose chern classes are identical, but whose total spaces are not homeomorphic?" I don't have a quick answer to this, but since it's  different from your original question, I don't feel obliged to.

Comment: You are absolutely right, of course: It is a different question! The original question was badly posed in this sense, because I implicitly assumed the bundles to have the same rank as this is the relevant case to me. I guess I should wait for a bit and then open another question... Thanks for your reply in any case!

Answer (score 3):

For a rank 2 vector bundle $E$ on $\mathbb{P}^3$ with $c_1 = 0$ there is an invariant, called $\alpha$-invariant, defined as the parity of $h^0(E(-2)) + h^1(E(-2))$. It allows to distinguish two topologically non-isomorphic bundles with the same Chern classes. For details see section I.6.1 of "Vector bundles on complex projective spaces" by Okonek, Schneider and Spindler.

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely the kind of example I was thinking of!

Comment: This is great! Indeed, I wouldn't be insulted at all if OP switched to *this* being the accepted answer, since it's not only correct, but more informative than mine. Of course, that's up to OP.